# How much MB of Data can we store in In-Memory Cache in .Net Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I am looking for help in .Net Core.

Can we store up to 30 MB Data in In-Memory cache in .Net Core web application.

Please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: **Yes**

Your cache can grow to almost any size as long as you have the RAM to handle it so 30 MB won't be a problem unless you are on a very limited device.

You can specify an optional "size" limit on your MemoryCache instance, but that is optional and defaults to there being no limit.

It also has some caveats that with how "size" is specified.

```
public class MyMemoryCache 
{
    public MemoryCache Cache { get; set; }
    public MyMemoryCache()
    {
        Cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions
        {
            SizeLimit = 1024
        });
    }
}


var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
    .SetSize(1)
    .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

// Save data in cache.
_cache.Set(MyKey, cacheEntry, cacheEntryOptions);
```

This will not limit the memory use by itself, but it will only allow 1024 objects of size 1 to be stored. You could of course calculate the size of the stored object and use that if you want, but it seems like a hassle.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-setsize-size-and-sizelimit-to-limit-cache-size

Comment: Computing physical in-memory item size is a huge hassle and actually not advisable because it depends on various things not in your control. I went through this discovery a couple of year ago myself: https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/2430

Comment: Yeah getting a definitive value might not be feasible but getting a ballpark value and using that for cache entry size could be done if that kind of control would be required. If you really need that kind of control over memory though then MemoryCache might not be the right tool at all.